# Finding all real functions satisfying $f(x) + f \left( \frac{x - 1}{x} \right) = \frac{5x^2 - x - 5}{x}$

Tags: functions

> Find all functions $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that satisfy
>   $$f(x) + f \left( \frac{x - 1}{x} \right) = \frac{5x^2 - x - 5}{x}$$
>   for all nonzero $x$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. Isolated problem statements without commentary of your own tends to give the wrong impression in this regard.)

Answer (score 1):

We set up a system of $3$ functional equations and one of the variables will be $f(x)$ and we will solve for it. First replace $x$ by $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and we get: $f(\frac{1}{1-x}) + f(x) = P(x)$, with $P(x)$ is the right hand side evaluated at $\frac{1}{1-x}$. Next replace $x$ by $\dfrac{x-1}{x}\implies f(\frac{x-1}{x})+f(\frac{1}{1-x}) = Q(x)$, with $Q(x)$ is the right hand side evaluated at $\frac{x-1}{x}$. Combine with the original equation: $f(x) + f(\frac{x-1}{x}) = \dfrac{5x^2-x-5}{x}$, you do have a system of "linear" equations in $3$ variables each of which is a function and your $f(x)$ is one of them, and you can solve for $f(x)$ by elimination method in a standard college algebra course.

Comment: +1 with additional comment to illustruate what is happening more explicitly: Let $T$ be a map $x \mapsto \frac{x-1}{x}=1 - \frac{1}{x}$. Then we have $$T\circ T(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{x}} = 1 - \frac{x}{x - 1} =\frac{-1}{x-1}$$ $$T\circ T \circ T(x) =\frac{-1}{1 - \frac{1}{x}-1} =x $$, which means $T\circ T \circ T = \operatorname{id}$. So one can have three formulas relating $f(x)$, $f(T(x)$, $f(T\circ T(x))$.